# Box2d: моделирования твердых тел

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы к статическому телу было наложено изображение. Не могу вычислить координаты перемещения этого тела и соответственно привязать к нему изображение.  Подскажите как это сделать без дополнительных библиотек если есть конечно такие варианты.

Оф сайт:http://box2d.org/

Вот пример кода:

```
function createBall(world, x, y, rad, fixed, /*optional*/ ballShapeName) {
    gNumBallsInPlay++;
    var ballSd = new b2CircleDef();
    if (!fixed) ballSd.density = gBallDensity;
    ballSd.radius = rad || 10;
    ballSd.restitution = .5;
    ballSd.friction = 0.01;
    if (ballShapeName != null) {
        ballSd.userData = {shapeName:ballShapeName};
    }
    else {
        ballSd.userData = {shapeName:"TestBall"};
    }
    var ballBd = new b2BodyDef();
    ballBd.position.Set(x,y);
    var ballBody = world.CreateBody(ballBd);
    ballBody.isBullet = true;
    ballBody.CreateShape(ballSd);
    ballBody.SetMassFromShapes();

    return ballBody;
};
```

Comment: К объекту картинка привязывается через userData, больше ни каких шаманств не нужно, внутренняя механика движка уже сама будет крутить и перемещать фикстуру как нужно. И "статическому телу было наложено изображение. Не могу вычислить координаты перемещения этого тела и соответственно привязать к нему изображение" вы противоречите самому себе - статическое тело потому и статическое, потому что его нельзя двигать. Что бы передвинуть тело нужно поменять тип на динамический.

Comment: Вы можете показать на этом примере, переменная ballBody и есть вроде динамическое тело. Как прикрепить к нему изображение ?